# Jquery replace href with name

Tags: jquery, replace

I have 26 lines scattered within the body of a single page that I need to make a change to via jquery in the HEAD of the file.

```
<a href="A">A</a>
<a href="B">B</a>
<a href="C">C</a>
<a href="D">D</a>
<a href="E">E</a>
<a href="F">F</a>
```

etc.

I need to make all 26 instances anchor links. So I need them to change from 'href' to 'name'. I don't have access to change the body content directly, hence jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/deekster/ufRxr/5/

(For demo purposes, I've manually corrected the first item - A. Make the 'result' window small in order to see the A anchor work). I appreciate anybody's reply.

Comment: What (code) have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: `$("a").each(function() { $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]); $(this).removeAttr("href"); });`

Comment: Maybe a combination of http://phpjs.org/functions/range/ and menu and page navigation using $(selector).html()?

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
$('a[href]').attr('name', function () {
    var href = this.href;
    return href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('#') + 1);
}).removeAttr('href');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eGMaX/)**

Or

```
$('a[href]').attr('name', function () {
    var href = this.href;
    this.removeAttribute('href');
    return href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('#') + 1);
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2XCeH/)**

Just another regex example:

```
$('ul a[href]').attr('name', function () {
    return this.href.match(/#([^#]*)$/)[1];
}).removeAttr('href');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8VSj5/)**

Comment: This generates `name` values such as `http://fiddle.jshell.net/eAkU9/show/A` (for example). `this.href` returns the complete URL, not the value of the `href` *attribute*.

Comment: @FelixKling Yup right,. fixed it.

Comment: Hi @PSL Thansk for replying. I've pasted your code to jsfiddle below, but alas it does not work:
http://jsfiddle.net/ufRxr/9/

Comment: @user2291964 you did not see the updated fiddle and answer, check that.

Comment: Why don't you just do `return this.href.substr(this.href.lastIndexOf('#') + 1);`? I _highly_ doubt accessing `this.href` twice will be worse than accessing `href` twice...

Comment: @ColeJohnson Least of the problems i would say, if at all you are true.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example:

```
// select all a element with an href attribute after a ul element
$('ul ~ a[href]').each(function(){
    // set the href attribute to name
   $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('href'));
    // remove attribute href
   $(this).removeAttr('href');
});
```

Note that I have replaced only the element after an `ul`. Maybe you can use some better selection. For example: `div.content a[href]` to select all the anchor inside a div with a class content.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZJ68/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

http://jsfiddle.net/ufRxr/10/

```
$('li a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('href').replace('#', ''));
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
});
```

Comment: I believe you have to remove the `href` attribute. Anchors can only have a `name` or an `href` property.

Comment: good catch @FelixKling updated it

Comment: @doitlikejustin I've added your update here, not working:
http://jsfiddle.net/deekster/ufRxr/13/
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a jQuery function that looks like this:

```
// for every a-tag that has an href attribute
$('a[href]').each(function() {
    // get the href attribute
    href = $(this).attr('href');
    // of the href does not start with '#'
    if (href.substr(0,1) != '#') { 
        // set the value form href to the name attribute
       $(this).attr('name', href);
        // remove the href attribute
       $(this).removeAttr('href');
    }
});
```

I have put the explanation in the comments, but feel free to ask if you want me to elaborate.

And the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ufRxr/8/